# Getting parameters error when using ibm_db_dbi sql query in python

Tags: sql, python-3.x, db2

I'm trying to use the results from one query to use in the where clause of another and cannot get it to work.  at the moment i'm getting an error....

> ProgrammingError: ibm_db_dbi::ProgrammingError: Exception('Statement Execute Failed: [IBM][CLI Driver] CLI0100E  Wrong number of parameters. SQLSTATE=07001 SQLCODE=-99999')

My code below (eventually, 'result' will just be a variable assigned to the results from another query, but for now i'm just trying to get it to work with a static variable.  Thanks in advance!

```
import ibm_db_dbi as db
result = ['c80fS4Pn1', '9f*hzNT21']
conn = db.connect('DRIVER=DB2 zOS;'
                     'DATABASE=xxxx;'
                     'HOSTNAME=xxxx.com;'  
                     'PORT=xxx;'
                     'PROTOCOL=xxxx;'
                     'UID=id;'
                     'PWD=passord;', '', '')
cur = conn.cursor()
sql = "SELECT * FROM SCHEMA.TABLE WHERE PRIM_KEY IN (?)"
cur.execute(sql, (result)) 
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you get error `CLI0100E` is because in your code-sample you show a list (called `result`) with two entries, while in your query there is a single parameter-marker `(?)`

The number of parameters to be bound (as done by the `cur.execute()`), must exactly match the number of parameter-markers in the query

As you usually do not know in advance the number of rows returned from a query, you usually don't know the number of parameter-markers in advance.

You could dynamically generate the number of parameter markers to match the number of rows in the previous result-set.  Or you could generate the SQL string in full without parameter markers which is inefficient and might not scale.

It is wise to do in SQL the things that SQL is good at doing, such as passing the results of a sub-query into another query. Trying to do that in client side code (instead of inside the SQL engine) may be inelegant and slow.

Comment: OK thanks for your answer. Unfortunately in this case, this is the only way, as joins and sub-queries here make the query run for so long that it breaks. =

Comment: i got it to work, in this case, the number of keys (rows) i'm pulling makes this workable and much faster than joins/nested.  thanks again, very helpful!